# What's the struct's initial sequence?

Tags: c++, struct, language-lawyer, unions

I came across the initial sequence concept. Serching through the Standard for `initial sequence` phrase gives only 3 results and they don't give a definition.

Section `N3797::9.5/1 [class.union]`:

> If a standard-layout union contains several standard-layout structs
>   that share a common *initial sequence* (9.2), and if an object of this
>   standard-layout union type contains one of the standard-layout
>   structs, it is permitted to inspect the common initial sequence of any
>   of standard-layout struct members;

I wish to look at an example which is demostrated that quote.

Comment: What prevents you from just writing up an example? key phrase "standard-layout union type contains one of the standard-layout structs"

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf What's the initial sequnce?

Comment: ["initial"](https://www.google.no/search?q=initial) = comes first. the data at the start of the struct.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf that's they appear in the initializer `struct A { int a = 5; }`, do they?

Comment: Oh. No. We're talking *memory layout*, placement in memory. With no intervening access specifiers this order is the same as declaration order. E.g. in `struct S { int a; int b; int c; };` the `a`, `b` and `c` in any given `S` instance are at increasing memory addresses.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I can't get the point what's the struct that _share_ common initial sequence? Are there structs that don't share it?

Comment: I think it is saying that for as long as the data members are of the same type, the padding between them will be the same and the members will properly alias one another. That means putting a number in using one struct's identifier can be accurately gotten out (from the same position) using a different struct's identifier *until* one of the structs contains a different type (in declaration order) to the other. (Is that explanation less complicated than the docs?)!

Comment: @Galik Sure. I'd like to clarify one more thing. I've written an example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa1f5f440732d901 If I understand you correclty, there is no UB in that example, right?

Comment: the key-phrase here is `common initial sequence`, the common part is important, if all struct's start with `int kind;` then thats the common initial sequence.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv According to my understading your example causes **no** UB. But that guarantee ends as soon as the types differ in declaration order.

Comment: @sp2danny So if both structs start with different kind of declration (e.g. int and float) then the common initial sequence is empty, is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it's talking about this kind of thing:

```
union U {
    struct S {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
    }
    struct T {
        int x;
        int y;
        float f;
    }
};
```

It's saying that it's OK to access either `U.S.a` or `U.T.x` and that they will be equivalent. Ditto for `U.S.b` and `U.T.y` of course. But accessing `U.T.f` after setting `U.S.c` would be undefined behaviour.

Comment: Is it necessary that `S.a, S.b` have tha same names as `T.a, T.b`?

Comment: Is the implication therefore that accessing `U.S.b` and `U.T.b` or `U.S.c` and `U.T.f` on the same struct undefined behaviour because I have always taken that to be the case.

Comment: accessing T.f is UB, if S.c was set. but a & b are part of the 'common initial sequence' and ok to access

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: I suspect the names of the fields don't matter, only the types, but I am not a "language lawyer". Answer updated to reflect this now.

Comment: @PaulR: The names don't influence the memory layout. I.e. the names don't matter.

Comment: @sp2danny: nope. c++11 9.2/19 "Two standard-layout structs share a common initial
sequence if corresponding members have layout-compatible types and either neither member is a bit-field or
both are bit-fields with the same width for a sequence of one or more initial members".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Let me ask you one more question. In the quote I cited in the initial post it's talking about _data-member_ of type struct, not a nested type `struct`, is it?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: Yes, data members, because we're talking about memory layout. The types can be locally defined or not, doesn't matter.