# Accessing same-type inactive member in unions

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, unions

I have something like this:

```
union DataXYZ
{
    struct complex_t
    {
        float real, imag;
    } complex;

    struct vector_t
    {
        float magnitude, phase;
    } vector;
};
```

I have some vectors of these, being general-purpose workspace memory, where I use the fields accordingly after the semantic context.

I know it's undefined behaviour to read a field in a union, when the last active member was another field (and type?). Does this matter when the types and layout match exactly?

I've been commenting on some other similar questions, asking for references that guarantee the behaviour, but nothing came up yet - hence this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Undefined behaviour with unions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273320/c-undefined-behaviour-with-unions)

Comment: Not a good duplicate. There's no standard ref.

Comment: This is actually legal.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560311/whats-the-structs-initial-sequence (but the answer bellow has more references).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Yes** you can read the other member in this **particular case**.

This is what the C++11/14 standard has to say:

> 9.5 - *Unions*
>
> In a union, at most one of the non-static data members can be active
>   at any time, that is, the value of at most one of the non-static data
>   members can be stored in a union at any time.

But the note immediately after the section makes your particular instance legal since one special guarantee is made *in order to simplify the use of unions*:

> [ *Note*: If a standard-layout union contains several standard-layout
>   structs that share a common initial sequence (9.2), and if an object
>   of this standard-layout union type contains one of the standard-layout
>   structs, it is permitted to inspect the common initial sequence of any
>   of standard-layout struct members; see 9.2. —*end note* ]

And your `struct`s **do share** a common initial sequence:

> 9.2.16 - *Class members*
>
> The common initial sequence of two standard-layout
>   struct (Clause 9) types is the longest sequence of non- static data
>   members and bit-fields in declaration order, starting with the first
>   such entity in each of the structs, such that corresponding entities
>   have layout-compatible types and either neither entity is a bit-field
>   or both are bit-fields with the same width.

Comment: The note immediately after the section you quoted makes this legal: " [Note: One special guarantee
is made in order to simplify the use of unions: If a standard-layout union contains several standard-layout
structs that share a common initial sequence (9.2), and if an object of this standard-layout union type
contains one of the standard-layout structs, it is permitted to inspect the common initial sequence of any of
standard-layout struct members; see 9.2. —end note]"

Comment: Given this answer has zero score and the comments could get interesting, I'll wiki it.

Comment: @Bathsheba 9.2.16 specify that the "initial sequence"  is "the longest sequence [...] such that entites have layout compatible types [...].", so I think in this case it is the whole struct since `float` and `float` obvisouly have layout compatible types.

Comment: See [class.mem]/16: "The common initial sequence of two standard-layout struct (Clause 9) types is the longest sequence of non-
static data members and bit-fields in declaration order, starting with the first such entity in each of the
structs, such that corresponding entities have layout-compatible types and either neither entity is a bit-field
or both are bit-fields with the same width". `A` and `B` in the standard's example is the same as in the case above.

Comment: It seems strange that this guarantee is given in a note: notes are not normative.

Comment: @Ruslan: As the cross-reference suggests, the normative wording is in [class.mem]/19 (/25 in the current draft).